# WebRTC onicecandidate fires 21 times. Is it OK?

Tags: webrtc

I'm learning WebRTC. As in tutorial I wrote a code:

```
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({'iceServers': [{ 'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]});
pc.onicecandidate = function (evnt) {
    console.log('GOT ICE CANDIDATE');
socket.emit('msg', { by: currentId, to: id, ice: evnt.candidate, type: 'ice' });
    iceCandidate = evnt.candidate;
};
pc.onaddstream = function (evnt) {
        console.log('Received new stream');
        remoteStream = evnt.stream;
};
```

And onicecandidate fires 21 times. So socket sends message 21 times. I'm confused is it OK that I have 21 iceCandidates and that socket sends message 21 times at this moment? Thank You
Here is log of candidates

```
 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 0, sdpMid: "audio", candidate: "candidate:3612426851 1 udp 2122260223 10.5.123.27 51569 typ host generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 0, sdpMid: "audio", candidate: "candidate:3612426851 2 udp 2122260223 10.5.123.27 51569 typ host generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 0, sdpMid: "audio", candidate: "candidate:2541423865 1 udp 2122129151 169.254.22.161 51570 typ host generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 0, sdpMid: "audio", candidate: "candidate:2541423865 2 udp 2122129151 169.254.22.161 51570 typ host generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 1, sdpMid: "video", candidate: "candidate:3612426851 1 udp 2122260223 10.5.123.27 51569 typ host generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 1, sdpMid: "video", candidate: "candidate:3612426851 2 udp 2122260223 10.5.123.27 51569 typ host generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 1, sdpMid: "video", candidate: "candidate:2541423865 1 udp 2122129151 169.254.22.161 51570 typ host generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 1, sdpMid: "video", candidate: "candidate:2541423865 2 udp 2122129151 169.254.22.161 51570 typ host generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 0, sdpMid: "audio", candidate: "candidate:2580725395 1 tcp 1518280447 10.5.123.27 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 0, sdpMid: "audio", candidate: "candidate:2580725395 2 tcp 1518280447 10.5.123.27 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 0, sdpMid: "audio", candidate: "candidate:3656970249 1 tcp 1518149375 169.254.22.161 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 0, sdpMid: "audio", candidate: "candidate:3656970249 2 tcp 1518149375 169.254.22.161 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 1, sdpMid: "video", candidate: "candidate:2580725395 1 tcp 1518280447 10.5.123.27 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 1, sdpMid: "video", candidate: "candidate:2580725395 2 tcp 1518280447 10.5.123.27 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 1, sdpMid: "video", candidate: "candidate:3656970249 1 tcp 1518149375 169.254.22.161 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 1, sdpMid: "video", candidate: "candidate:3656970249 2 tcp 1518149375 169.254.22.161 0 typ host tcptype active generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 0, sdpMid: "audio", candidate: "candidate:2114899382 1 udp 1686052607 213.230.83.5… srflx raddr 10.5.123.27 rport 51569 generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 0, sdpMid: "audio", candidate: "candidate:2114899382 2 udp 1686052607 213.230.83.5… srflx raddr 10.5.123.27 rport 51569 generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 1, sdpMid: "video", candidate: "candidate:2114899382 1 udp 1686052607 213.230.83.5… srflx raddr 10.5.123.27 rport 51569 generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  RTCIceCandidate {sdpMLineIndex: 1, sdpMid: "video", candidate: "candidate:2114899382 2 udp 1686052607 213.230.83.5… srflx raddr 10.5.123.27 rport 51569 generation 0"}
conversation.client.controller.js:14 GOT ICE CANDIDATE:  null
```

Comment: yes it is ok. Your candidates contain both UDP and TCP for both private and public IPs and audio and video and some for udp srflx for audio and video. All for Rtp and Rtcp. (You should probably hide your public IP information...). What specifically do you think would be the issue?

Comment: Benjamin Trent, thank you for response. I didn't mean any issue, I just never had work with ICE and WebRTC, so I expected only 1 candidate. I didn't know it will be so much. But thank you I know. About hiding public IP: How can I hide my public IP. What can you advice

Comment: Hide it from the post :) not in the candidates themselves

Comment: Benjamin Trent, thank you