# WebRTC OnIceCandidate fired multiple times

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to build a online Chess game application that uses WebRTC for the 2 players to talk with. I found that OnIceCandidate was fired 4 times and thus 4 ICEs (or candidates?) are generated. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926984/webrtc-onicecandidate-fires-21-times-is-it-ok) says mulitple firing is okay. My question is, should the other player get all ICEs? Or certain ICE or any is good enough?

> {'sdpMid': 'sdparta_0', 'sdpMLineIndex': 0, 'candidate': 'candidate:0
>   1 UDP 2122121471 1.2.3.121 57386 typ host'}
>
> {'sdpMid': 'sdparta_0', 'sdpMLineIndex': 0, 'candidate': 'candidate:2
>   1 UDP 2122187007 1.2.3.112 57387 typ host'}
>
> {'sdpMid': 'sdparta_0', 'sdpMLineIndex': 0, 'candidate': 'candidate:4
>   1 UDP 2122055935 192.168.56.1 57388 typ host'}
>
> {'sdpMid': 'sdparta_0', 'sdpMLineIndex': 0, 'candidate': 'candidate:6
>   1 UDP 2122252543 2002:824a:1479::824a:1479 57389 typ host'}
>
> {'sdpMid': 'sdparta_0', 'sdpMLineIndex': 0, 'candidate': 'candidate:3
>   1 UDP 1685987327 192.231.71.2 57387 typ srflx raddr 10.88.33.112 rport
>   57387'}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is, should the other player get all ICEs? Or certain ICE or any is good enough?

Other player should get all the candidates to perform the ICE negotiation.

Comment: To elaborate, this is known as trickle ice,  which basically means that you're sending each ice candidate to the other side as you gather them so that they can begin checking each candidate and find a match as soon as possible.

Comment: If you want to avoid sending each individual ICE candidate you can wait until you receive a null candidate which means the ICE collection has completed. At that point you can grab the SDP which will contain all the candidates.